# Yii dropdownlist saving value in ivar onclick

Tags: php, yii

how can I save value as ivar from dropDownlist in yii? here my code, which doesn't work :/
declaration of ivar:

```
public $blaaa;
```

and my dropdownlist code:

```
 echo CHtml::dropDownList(
                'categoryDropDownList',
                '',
                CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
                array(
                    'empty' => 'Select Category',
                    'onchange'=>function () {
                            $this->blaaa = 'js:this.value';
                        }
                    ));
```

I tried also with ajax, but it also doesnt work:

```
'ajax' => array(
    'type' => 'POST',
    'url' => CController::createUrl('category/actionBla'),
    'data' => array('id' => 'js:this.value')
```

where

```
public function bla()
{
    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
         $this->blaaa = $_POST['id'];
}
```

thanks in advance for help!

Comment: what is the error message you are getting? any js error?

Comment: nope, any error unfortunatly. It seems $blaa is still empty, so js doesn't transfer data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with echo'ing CHtml::dropDownList in form:

```
echo CHtml::form();
    echo CHtml::dropDownList(
        'categoryDropDownList',
        '',
        CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
        array(
            'empty' => 'Select Category'
        ));
echo CHtml::endForm();
```

and now activeForm bother about sending parameters via POST

Answer (score 0):

In ajax section, change url as below

```
'url' => CController::createUrl('category/bla'),
```

In controller, your function name should be

```
public function actionBla()
```

Comment: Did you print_r($_POST); in actionBla()?

Comment: check your ajax call and post data in browser console.